# prevent Uglify.JS from adding some changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minify, uglifyjs

I am using Uglify.Js for my code and I am facing some hard times, the main part that drives me crazy is my code contains
`return x + await a + await b;`
and when I use Uglify.Js(code, codeSettings) the code turned to `return x + await (a + await b);`
this is my codesettings:

```
CodeSettings codeSettings = new CodeSettings();
CodeSettings codeSettings = new CodeSettings();
codeSettings.MinifyCode = false;
codeSettings.OutputMode = OutputMode.MultipleLines;
codeSettings.BlocksStartOnSameLine = BlockStart.SameLine;
codeSettings.IndentSize = 1;
code = Uglify.Js(code, codeSettings).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after spending a while I came with some changes, since my purpose of using the Uglify.Js was just for removing comments and unnecessary whitespace, so I used another JavaScript minifier which is lighter and do just what I wanted.

the Minifier that I have used is JSMin by Douglas Crockford:

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.cs